# I have encountered these errors in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I've recently started working with android studio and encountered these errors:

1. Could not install Gradle distribution from 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-bin.zip'
2. Missing essential plugin: org.jetbrains.android

I have tried different things to resolve these errors, like reinstalling Android studio from scratch. Any way to tackle these errors?

Comment: Are you on Windows ?

Comment: Yes, I am on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing Android Studio is a messy thing in windows. Multiple modules are installed in multiple folders in cdrive.

So, removing android studio completely is a messy thing.

1. For the 1st error, you can download the respective gradle zip file and save it in *.gradle* folder inside *C:/Users/username/*. But this will not work with newer android versions.
2. For the 2nd error, you should delete a file named  '*disabled_plugins.txt*' which will be found inside *C:/Users/username/AppData/Roaming/Google/AndroidStudioxyz.v*
   The same file is also found in *Local/Google/AndroidStudioxyz.v* also.
   So, deleting these files will solve this error.

But, a better way to resolve both the errors is to remove and reinstall Android studio from scratch.
To remove android studio, make sure to remove any folder having the name Android in the following folders:

1. *C:/Users/username/*. Here delete **.android** & **.gradle** folders. Do not delete *AndroidStudioProjects* folder, because your projects will be deleted.
2. *C:/Users/username/AppData/Roaming/Google/*.
3. *C:/Users/username/AppData/Local/Google/*
4. **C:/Program Files/Android**
5. *C:/Microsoft/*  not must to delete.

Now install your android studio again.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Delete the following file and retry

```
C:\Users\YOUR_USER\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.2\disabled_plugins.txt
```

For MacOS users, the file is located in

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.2
```